# Representation Theorem on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory

Bogachev's book on Gaussian measures states: *"A measure $\gamma$ on a locally convex space $X$ is Gaussian iff its Fourier transform has the for $$\hat{\gamma}(f) = \exp \bigg{(}iL(f)-\frac{1}{2}B(f,f)\bigg{)}$$ where $L$ is a linear function on $X^{*}$ and $B$ is a bilinear function on $X^{*}$ such that the quadratic form $f \mapsto B(f,f)$ is nonegative.*

Now, my question is concerned about the opposite direction. Suppose I have defined a bilinear map $B:\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})\times \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. Do we have any representation theorem for $\exp\bigg{(}-\frac{1}{2}B(f,f)\bigg{)}$? Can we write it as a Fourier transform of some measure on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ so that, because of Bogachev's statement, this measure is Gaussian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes but you are forgetting a crucial hypothesis: the bilinear form $B$ must be a **continuous** map from $\mathcal{S}'\times\mathcal{S}'$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
For a proof of the result (analogue of Bochner-Minlos for probability measures on $\mathcal{S}$ instead of $\mathcal{S}'$) see Theorem 4.3 in the article 
["Generalized random fields and Lévy's continuity theorem on the space of tempered distributions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09326) by Biermé, Durieu and Wang.

Comment: again, thanks for the answer. Putting all together: here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461844/sine-gordon-transformation-and-minlos-theorem/3469666#3469666 ) you said I need extra assumptions on the potential. Consider the bilinear form $B(f,g) := (f\otimes g)(\phi)$ where $\phi(x,y) = v(x-y)$ is my two-body interaction. In principle, if my assumptions lead to the continuity of $B$, I can use the theorem you mentioned above and than take $f$ and $g$ as $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\epsilon_{j}\delta(x_{j})$, where the $\epsilon_{j}$ are the charges of a configuration...

Comment: ...and then prove the sine-gordon transformation for more general two-body interactions between charges? Is it possible to prove it this way?

Comment: more general interactions means that my potential need not to be a double integral involving mollifiers, it could be just, I don't know, smooth and positive-definite or something else.